# Keyword searching AND Filtering in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have to search for keywords in one field and an exact match in a different field. I have tried something but it does not seem to work at all.

I tried giving the full article with the author as i have put in AWS ElasticSearch but it still won't retrieve anything.

```
query=json.dumps({
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "article": "man killed kim jones"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "author": "Barbara Boyer"                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
response = requests.get(url-ES-domain/data/_search?",headers=headers,data=(query))
response.json()
```

Mapping details

```
{
"mappings": {
    "article": {
      "full_name": "article",
      "mapping": {
        "article": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is for the keyword in the article. Even if I give the full article as it is in the ES index, it still won't give any hits.

Comment: Maybe the lowercase? Article could be "Man killed Kim Jones" or variations on that?

Comment: Can you add mapping and document data

Comment: Did you try the it on  kibana query?

Comment: @powerPixie The article contained these exact words as I manually put them in.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal I just learned about mapping; just a beginner at elastic search so trying different things. The mapping is :
 ` ` `
{"data":{"mappings":{"article":{"full_name":"article","mapping":{"article":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}}
 ` ` `
@AlwaysSunny No, i don't have any use for Kibana as of now

Comment: Add sample data

Comment: And the mapping for each field:


`{"data":{"mappings":{"properties":{"article":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"author":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"key":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"publication":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"title":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}`

Comment: Add it in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

**Mappings**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "lc_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 20
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "article": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "lc_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "key": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "publication": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {  
      "must" : {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query": "man killed kim jones",
          "fields":     [ "article", "title" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "author.keyword": "Maddie Hanna"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query returns matches and returns the document you have added to the document.

When you are searching for a multi-word match, I suggest you use the `match_phrase` query. By default, elasticsearch will create keyword mapping for the text fields.

Note: You can try these things using [Kibana UI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/introduction.html) provided by the elastic team. It will save a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked very well! I will be sure to keep mappings and a proper query structure in mind the next time .